Нужна ли нам Политота?
У нас на сайте есть чат с названием:

Политота на ru.SO

Зачем нам это чат?

Разве в сети недостаточно мест где можно поговорить на эту тему?

В описании чата говорится:

Всевозможные политические баталии и демагогия на русском языке.

Никаких баталий там нет. Там теперь есть только два человека с одинаковыми политическими взглядами. Никто с ними не спорит. Тоесть чат используется не по назначению.


Нужен ли нам вообще этот чат?
PS: Голосуйте в комментариях.

Да это чат нам нужен.

Нет этот чат нам не нужен.

Если чат станет не нужен, он сам отсохнет и удалится со временем. Если он жив, значит кому-то нужен.

А кому и чем он мешает? До этого вопроса я и не знал, что такой чат есть... И самое главное - что принесёт его закрытие?

Ну есть и есть - никому ж не мешает. Даже модераторам не мешает. Так чего его трогать?

Нужен. Точка
Тут есть пользователи, которые хоть и не частые, но поситители данного чата. Он живет уже несколько лет и нет веских причин его закрывать.
Надоели уже эти игры в демократию с голосованием.

Интересно, чем вам голосования надоели? Предлагаете без них все авторитарно делать? )

@Kromster Не несут реальной пользы и смысловой нагрузки. Шум ради шума. Поэтому я и называю  это "игры в демократию". А если погружаться в более общие проявления демократий в нашей жизни, то я против таких "демократий". Власть народа, блин;)

Не воняет - не трогай. Завоняет - убери.
